# Creating a search engine

Tags: php, sql, search

I'm trying to create a search engine to search for users based on their name.

Here is an example of what I can do at this moment:
I want to search for david (surname) Jones (name)
-> When I type: 'Da' or 'vid' or 'J' or 'ones' it gives me David Jones
BUT when I type 'David J' it gives nothing.

In which way do I have to change my query to search on both fields on the same time?

The query:

```
    public function Search($searchinput)
    {
            $db = new Db();
            $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE name LIKE '%" . $searchinput . "%' OR surname LIKE'%" . $searchinput . "%'";
            $result = $db->conn->query($select);
            return $result;

}
```

Comment: Since you are matching against natural language texts you should break things down to a word based approach. Words are separated by whitesapce chars in natural languages. So _always_ separate the available input by whitespaces and search for the individual "words" you gain by that. Then combine the search results. That is what one would expect instinctively.

Comment: [link](http://toabigo.net23.net/) have a look at my old search engine project pure php

Answer (score 0):

Try this query using `CONCAT`:

```
$select = "SELECT * FROM  tblusers WHERE name LIKE '%". $searchinput ."%' OR surname LIKE '%".  $searchinput ."%' OR CONCAT(name,' ',surname) LIKE '%". $searchinput ."%' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

probably for production you can use http://sphinxsearch.com/ because it is MUCH faster than MySQL in searching texts in natural language

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to match David J in name or surname but as I see your db look as like follows:

```
Name  | Surnam
Davud | Jones
```

And your like statement is looking for: "David J" into name or surname which give you the right result(zero) because there does not exist any row with name or surname like "David J", in your case the best solution will be to concat the name with surname and then to make like statment upon them:

```
Select * FROM tbulsers WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE "%David J%"
```

Comment: I tried those 2 sql statements but none of them is working:  $select = "SELECT * FROM tblusers WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '% . $searchinput . %' ";

$select = "SELECT * FROM  tblusers WHERE name LIKE '%". $searchinput ."%' OR surname LIKE '%".  $searchinput ."%' OR CONCAT(name,' ',surname) LIKE '%". $searchinput ."%' ";

Comment: I dont see anything else there please verify your db rows any give us feedback. Regards